# Condition joining in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, conditional-statements

I want to dynamically join 2 tables in SQL Server that means according to table value count, as `LEFT` join or `RIGHT` join.. Is it possible in SQL Server ? If yes please explain

Thanks in advance

Comment: I really don't understand what is your need. Please, explain better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to conditionally do a `left join` or `right join`.

However, as both of these joins are essentially a filtered `full outer join`, could you use that and then use `where` clauses to get what you want?

However this seems less than ideal, and I would question why you need to do this in the first place.